# iOS access music files, possible?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, itunes

Is it possible to access the raw music files of iTunes library? If so, how? I looked around but could only find how to get the meta data, not access to the actual music files.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing you may get AVAssetReader. According to documentation it allows:

> Read raw un-decoded media samples directly from storage, obtain samples decoded into renderable forms.

That gives you raw media samples, but no raw access to the whole file data.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well...ok i'll just explain to you my idea: I am trying create an app where users can share music with each other. So bunch of friends get together, one iPhone connected to the dock (maybe in the car), and all the friends send their music to that iPhone that is connected and it plays that music. My aim is to do this server side where music is sent to a central server which then pushes it off to the "main"/"master" device and it is played there.

Comment: I don't get why you would want to send the music to a server, when you could use a local wifi/bluetooth connection to the device that should play. But basically AVAssetReader should give you all you need. There might even be a better way to achieve this phone2phone AirPlay. There's a ton of APIs that let you access audio data at different abstraction levels. Look at MediaPlayer.framework or CoreAudio.